# Embedding Images to Emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, internet-explorer-8, gmail

I have created a C# Webform progam for sending reminder emails to clients on my webpage.

It works fine in Outlook. and in Gmail on FireFox.

I just discovered (i dont use IE) that in IE 8 in gmail it doesn't display the image?

It just has an X and alt text.

I cant figure out why IE 8 and gmail wont dispaly the images and i have played with it a bit.

in C#:

```
LinkedResource emo2 = new LinkedResource(logoPath);
emo2.ContentId = "logo";
emo2.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(emo2);
```

and in my HTML file :

```
<img id="header" alt="MyWebpage" src="cid:logo" />
```

Sending Newsletters via Email is SO frustrating with all the differnent clients. but i never thought Gmail would be my problem!

Comment: What does the resulting MIME structure look like?

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar requirement to embed images in to the HTML email instead of link to the images hosted on our website. The main difference being that the user doesn't need to click "show all images" in their email client, i.e. the email should appear immediately rendered to the recipient.

We created the embedded images and it worked great in Outlook and some other email clients, but we discovered that some email clients don't like them as you've noticed with gmail. After a couple of days researching and trying different things, we concluded that there is no silver bullet to make your email correctly show it's embedded images in all major email clients.

We settled and just hosted the images on our website (which means the user gets the "show all images" button...), and used something like:

```
<img src="http://website/image.jpg"/>
```

If you have the patience, you could embed images for all email addresses except for certain address (such as @gmail.com), but my preference would be consistency and hence just link to the images.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the end of LinkedResource:

```
logoPath, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

Assuming your logo is a JPG of course!
Also, is htmlView and AlternateView ?

Comment: yes htmlview is an alternateview... its actually a png but ill try that thanks! (worst case will convert to jpg)

Comment: I converted it to jpg and dded that but its still showing as a X in gmail with IE :(

Comment: Oh, that's a shame; that's the only difference between the code you posted earlier and some code we use in production.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer but I bet the jpg you are embedding isn't an RBG jpg, its probably CMYK.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem by looking at an existing email with embedded images that was working on IE. Apparently IE is very picky about the content that needs to be shown. Even though I was adding content type

```
var imgContentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

It was not showing up in IE. Then I looked at an existing email and the Image in it had the content type "image/png; name="image1.png". Once I added the name to the content type, the images started to show up. I guess IE needs the image extension to know what to do with the image src